# How to use JSON Sanitizer at Server Side?

Tags: json, owasp, sanitization, jsonexception

I want to implement the 'JSON Sanitizer' validation as mentioned by OWASP. 
My understanding is that this needs to be done in two places:

1. JSON data (in Request) received from Client or Other Systems - This needs to be sanitized at Server side before being processed
2. JSON data (in Response) to be sent to Client - This needs to be sanitized at Server side before being sent to client

Is it sufficient that I just call a sanitizing method in JSON
Sanitizing library on that JSON Data ?

Will that perform all sanitization or are there any other validations to be done in this regard ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [OWASP JSON Sanitizer](https://github.com/OWASP/json-sanitizer) converts JSON-like input to syntactically valid & embeddable JSON.

It is typically used to take “JSON” produced by ad-hoc methods on the server like

```
"{ \"output\": " + stringOfJson + " }"
```

and make sure it's *syntactically valid* so that it can be passed to `JSON.parse` on the client, and *embeddable* so that it can be embedded in a larger HTML or XML response like

```
<script>var jsonUsedByScriptsOnPage = {$myJson};</script>
```

You can definitely use it on your server if your clients are likely to send dodgy JSON.

Note that your server still needs to treat the JSON as untrusted just as it would any other string it receives in a response that does not arrive with valid credentials.

https://github.com/OWASP/json-sanitizer#security explains

> sanitizing JSON cannot protect an application from [Confused Deputy attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem)
>
> ```
> var myValue = JSON.parse(sanitizedJsonString);
> addToAdminstratorsGroup(myValue.propertyFromUntrustedSource);
> ```

Comment: this helps. so how can ensure that the JSON Payload does not have any malicious script to do attacks like XSS ? is there any other library that can validate if the JSON payload has any script content ?

Comment: by >dodgy< do you mean incorrect format or malicious content (but correctly formatted) ?

Comment: @yathirigan, Both.  If an otherwise trustworthy client sends you JSON composed by ad-hoc methods, `'{ "secret": "' + secret + '", "foo": "' + foo + '" }'` then an attacker could cause that client to send you a message that violates some contract between you.  For example, if they cause foo to be `'\", \"otherProperty\": \"value'` then they've effectively introduced a property that the client did not expect to be there.  No amount of sanitization that sees only the string can reinforce property or object boundaries.

Comment: The library does well, but doesn't cope with quotes screening - it splits string into several fields instead. Had to write own `JsonUtils.sanitize()`.

Comment: @Zon We are also at the point writing our own method. Are you able to share yours?

Comment: @Lonzak see my answer below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66212886/1112963. I've started with an expanding directed approach, see if it's not too limiting for you.

Answer (score 1):

The OWASP JSON Sanitizer doesn't cope with quotes screening - **it splits string into several fields** instead. So I've written **own sanitize method**, quite primitive though - if you see any security caveats, I'm open to suggestions, please share.

```
/**
 * Helper methods to validate data.
 */
@UtilityClass
public class ValidationUtils {

/**
 * Removes disallowed symbols from string to prevent input injection.
 * @param input User input with possible injection.
 * @return Value without injection-sensible symbols.
 */
public String sanateInjection(String input){
    return input.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: This filters out everything which is not an alphanumerical character (and blank). Where do you apply it to? To the full json string? Or to values only? Because this filters out many valid characters like `.,;-_=` I mean if you run this, your strings are definitely save ;-)

Comment: Yupp. Only to field input, usually alphanumeric. You have to expand logics if you expect text input with chars that could be used to create an injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

I want to know whether some json string contains `<script>` tags which can later be used to execute dynamic content. But since the return value of the `sanitize()`method would escape it there is no way to detect whether something like that is in there. So the following works for me:

```
public static String checkJsonForScripts(String input) {
    if (!JsonSanitizer.sanitize(input).equals(input)) {
        log.error("Problematic string found" + input);
        throw new YourException(...);
    }
    return input;
}
```