# Using Jackson/Java to ensure that and all serialization to JSON delimits untrusted data within single or double quotes escapes any special characters?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fortify

I have the following Fortify security issue:

> JSON Injection: Ensure that all serialization is performed using a safe serialization function that delimits untrusted data within single or double quotes and escapes any special characters.

Below is my code:

```
public String saveJson(String json, long ID, String userId) throws SQLException, JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        List<item> listOfNewItems = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<item>>(){});
        userId= userFactory.getUser().getID();
        String message = saveJson(listOfNewItems,ID,userId);

        return message;
    }
```

I am trying to maybe use

```
org.codehaus.jackson.io.JsonStringEncoder.getInstance().quoteAsString(json);
```

or maybe

```
objectMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.QUOTE_FIELD_NAMES, false);
            objectMapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
```

but not sure?

More details on the error:

> writes unvalidated input into JSON

Any ideas?

Comment: The issue description you posted talks about serialization, but the code you posted actually performs DEserialization. Are you asking for help with serialization or deserialization?

Comment: Maybe you need to sanitize the JSON string before deserializing it?  There's a [json sanitizer](https://github.com/owasp/json-sanitizer) by [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) that looks like it's fit for purpose.  [Here's a short discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791629/how-to-use-json-sanitizer-at-server-side) of it from a few years back.  If you need field-by-field processing, you're probably looking at custom (de)serialization.  [This might be a start.](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Comment: Can you provide an example of json which does not use the specialized serialization function and another version of secure json which used the specialized serialization function. Default ObjectMapper should handle your requirement. Why change the configuration?

Answer (score 2):

The comments so far from `mikaelhg` and `gagan singh` are correct:

1. Jackson `ObjectMapper` on its default settings will already "Ensure that all serialization is performed using a safe serialization function that delimits untrusted data within single or double quotes and escapes any special characters."
2. The code you have shown is deserialization, not serialization (and/or is broken or incorrectly copied)

Comment: Thank you Rich. The quoted text in your first point is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: (I quoted that from your question)

Comment: Hah, so you did. Does the Objectmapper documentation state this fact in a simple, straightforeward way as in the quoted text?

Comment: I doubt it is stated directly, as it I think it is self-evident from the design goals. The library would not be able to "round trip" arbitrary strings from Java -> JSON -> Java if it did not do escaping properly.

Comment: I had a look in the Jackson docs and couldn't find any similar statement. I think the authors just consider it self-evident. Searching for things like "does jackson json escape strings" gave blog posts like http://javausecase.com/2017/02/22/are-escaping-special-characters-in-json-string-required/